# Passing char* as an argument prevents function from working

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, char

I'm really sorry for phrasing badly my question, but really I have no idea how to be more precise. I don't really understand the problem I have. First, here is my code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
int gettimeofday();

void lance_commande(char *commande)
    {
        int res;
        float t1,t2;
        t1=gettimeofday();
        res=system(commande);
        t2=gettimeofday();
        printf("Temps écoulé : %f secondes\n",t2-t1);
        if(res==-1)
            {
                printf("Une erreur est survenue\n");
            }
    }


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int i;
        if (argc>1)
            {
                for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
                    {
                        lance_commande(argv[i]);
                        printf("\n");
                    }
            }
        else
        {
            printf("Aucun argument n'a été passé en entrée");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

What my program does is execute some shell command with the function lance_commande, the commands I want to execute are passed as an argument when I start my program from shell, like that: `./program "command1" "command2" ...`
When I execute the code I pasted with the arguments : `./program "sleep 1" "sleep 2"` , it outputs  `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)` . I'm a beginner in C so I don't really understand why it happens, I heard it's some problem with memory access but still I don't know how to fix it.

In my main function, in the for loop, when instead of calling `lance_command` function, I call system() function, the commands run perfectly.

In my `lance_command` function, when I call `system(*commande)`, I tried using commande instead of `*commande` as a parameter, and the output I received changed :

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have no idea what's happening, could someone help me please understand what's the problem ? Sorry if the answer of my question already exists, but I don't know what kind of problem I should look for.

EDIT: I made a modification to remove the warning about int to char* conversion for the output of system() function, and replaced `*commande` with `commande` as a parameter of system function, while still having `*commande` as parameter of lance_commande function.
The error didn't change, `./program "sleep 1" "sleep 2"`  outputs

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `system(commande)`?

Comment: First, enable all compiler warnings and fix the warnings. The type of the return value of `system` is `int`, not `char*`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError `i<argc` is correct. `argv[argc]` would be a `NULL` pointer, and `argv[0]` is the program name that should be skipped. But the check for the number of arguments should be `if(argc > 1)` because it will be 1 if no argument was passed.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Yeah I thought it would be ```system(commande)``` too, but that doesn't fix the problem and triggers the output I wrote in the last paragraph instead. Also thanks for your information @Bodo, I fixed it, but that did not change the issues. And my foor loop is correct, argc is the lenght of argv so should not be reached, and argv is always set at 1 as a minimum , it's the address of main() I think. So I only want to parse the other arguments

Comment: Note: you dont need the `if (argc>=1)` condition; it is already covered by the loop condition.

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks for making me notice, actually I meant ```argc>1```

Comment: @wildplasser The check is supposed to print an error message when the program is run without arguments, but it must be `if(argc>1)` to work as intended.

Comment: Then:  Negate te condition, and exit() early. [but: it is a matter of style, I agree]

Comment: @Francesco When you have fixed the warnings, [edit] your question and copy&paste the modified program, the comman line and the output. Otherwise we don't see if there are still any errors.

Comment: The function `gettimeofday` returns a success/error indication and requires pointers as arguments to return the result. Your wrong declaration `int gettimeofday();` hides this error which may also result in a segmentation fault. To get the time in seconds you probably need something like `t1 = time(NULL);`. For `gettimeofday` you need `#include <sys/time.h>`.

Comment: @Francesco To see values are actually used in your program you should run it in a debugger or add some debug output, e.g. `printf("calling system(%s)\n", commande);` before `res=system(commande);`.

Comment: Thanks @Bodo for your help. I'll try doing as you said and see if it fixes the problems. I have a feeling you're right because removing the time calculations I performed make the function run smoothly. I'll keep you updated

Comment: If you want to get the time including fractions of a second, you could use `gettimeofday` and combine the seconds and microseconds values to a `float` value. If you try to convert the individual time values to `float` you will get problems because the number of seconds is normally big, so it is better to first subtract the two seconds values, then add/subtract the microseconds.

Comment: @Francesco Then you can write your own answer and show the working code.

Comment: I wrote it as an edit, I didn't see  I could write it as an answer, I'll do it

Comment: @Francesco You can still add an answer and remove the edit. See https://onlinegdb.com/SJGy5EFW_ for my solution

Comment: Thanks a lot for spending all this time  to help me @Bodo ! Your way of printing the time difference definitely seems better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem has been solved, as mentioned in the edit.  Thanks to @Bodo for the help.
Here is the final code, using gettimeofday :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>


void lance_commande(char *commande)
    {
        int res;
        struct timeval t1,t2;
        gettimeofday(&t1,NULL);
        res=system(commande);
        gettimeofday(&t2,NULL);
        printf("Duration : %ld seconds et %ld microseconds\n",t2.tv_sec-t1.tv_sec,t2.tv_usec-t1.tv_usec);
        if(res==-1)
            {
                printf("Error\n");
            }
    }


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int i;
        if (argc>1)
            {
                for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
                    {
                        lance_commande(argv[i]);
                        printf("\n");
                    }
            }
        else
        {
            printf("No input provided");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The correct way to set the parameter for the system() function in my lance_commande() function was `system(commande)` in the end.

The reason why the code was crashing is because of the gettimeofday declaration. I wrongly explicitly declared it, resulting in a segmentation fault. I removed the declaration and included sys/time.h, the warning about implicit declaration disappeared.

After reading explanation about gettimeofday (https://linuxhint.com/gettimeofday_c_language/), I managed to understand how it worked and print the amount of seconds and microseconds spent. As @Bodo pointed out, using t1=time(NULL) [same for t2 after] would have been a better solution, but using gettimeofday was a must for me.

Comment: Your way of printing the time difference does not correctly handle the case of carry-over from the microseconds to the seconds. Example: `tv1.tv_sec = 1`, `tv1.tv_usec = 999000`, `tv2.tv_sec = 3`, `tv2.tv_usec = 1000` would print "2 seconds et -998000 microseconds" instead of "1 seconds et 2000 microseconds". You can fix this by something like `if(t2.tv_usec < t1.tv_usec) { t2.tv_usec += 1000000; t2.tv_sec -= 1; }`